# No Difference Between Boolean Operators AND and OR in Case Conditional in Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, boolean-operations

I can't see a practical difference between the boolean operators AND and OR in a Ruby case conditional.

For example, I want to get the user to input the sentence:

```
sudo make me a sandwich
```

And the case conditional starts as follows:

```
case user_selection
when /sudo/ && /sandwich/
```

However, if the user enters:

```
make me a sandwich
```

The condition will be a satisfied.

My way around it in this instance is to re-order the conditions:

```
case user_selection
when /sandwich/ && /sudo/
```

But that pre-supposes that every time a user thinks to use "sudo" they will include the string "sandwich" in their response.  However, this is functionally no different from this:

```
case user_selection
when /sudo/
```

I looked up boolean operators for Ruby conditionals, but have not found a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `&&` in a case block like that, because `when /sudo/ && /sandwich/` evaluates to just `when /sandwich/`.

Instead you will need to use *one* regexp that looks for both words. A simple example might be:

```
case user_selection
when /sudo.*sandwich/
```

Comment: Fun fact, you can use a comma separated list to `OR` them together, as in `when /a/, /b/`

Comment: Thanks @akuhn, I know about the comma -- pretty handy for those that don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference.

If you absolutely need a logical AND in your case statement, you could use a lambda :

```
def answer(order)
  case order
  when ->(x) { x =~ /sudo/ && x =~ /sandwich/ }
    puts 'Okay'
  else
    puts 'Do it yourself!'
  end
end

answer 'make me a sandwich'
#=> Do it yourself!
answer 'sudo sing a song'
#=> Do it yourself!
answer 'sudo make me a sandwich'
#=> Okay
```

If you can compact the boolean logic to a single check (e.g. with a Regex), you probably should, as in @spickermann's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789089/6419007).

Comment: Downvoter : Please state what's wrong with my answer. It works, it answers the question but still states that the alternative from spickermann is better.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful too.